# Undefined Wrapper Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, password-encryption

I'm having a trouble understanding why I cannot successfully call my wrapper method in my User model.  My problem lies with this line `self.password_hash = hash_check(password, password_salt)` in the encrypt_password method shown below.  My hash_check method works correctly in the authenticate method so I'm a bit stumped.  When I run my test I get the error `undefined method 'hash_check' for #<User:0x007f94851a5f88>`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password

  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = generate_salt
      self.password_hash = hash_check(password, password_salt)
    end
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_user(email)
    user && user.password_hash == hash_check(password, user.password_salt) ? user : nil
  end

  def self.find_user(email)
    user = find_by_email(email)
  end

  private

  def self.hash_check(password, password_salt)
    BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
  end

  def generate_salt
    BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
  end
end

require 'spec_helper'

describe 'User' do
  let(:user) { User.create(email: 'user@gmail.com', password: "secure_password") }

  it 'creates a user object' do
    user.should be_kind_of User
  end

  describe '.find_user' do
    let(:valid_user_search) { User.find_user('user@gmail.com') }
    let(:invalid_user_search) { User.find_user('notregistered@gmail.com') }

    it 'returns a user by their email' do
      user.should == valid_user_search
    end

    it 'return nil if no user if found' do
      invalid_user_search.should == nil
    end
  end

  describe '.authenticate' do
    let(:auth_user) { User.authenticate(user.email, user.password) }
    let(:non_auth_user) { User.authenticate('notregistered@gmail.com', 'invalidpass') }

    it 'returns an valid user' do
      auth_user.should == user
    end

    it 'returns nil on an invalid user' do
      non_auth_user.should == nil
    end
  end

  describe '.encrypt_password' do
    it 'returns a password salt'
    it 'return a password hash'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.hash_check` is a class method (because you put `self`).  It works in `self.authenticate` because it is also a class method, (as it doesn't rely on an instance).  HOWEVER, it won't work on an instance method like `encrypt_password` because you are not invoking the class method at all.

So you are going to need to replace `hash_check(password, password_salt)` in your instance method with `self.class.hash_check(password, password_salt)` or `User.hash_check(password, password_salt)` to be able to use a class method

Read more about the nuances [here](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)